# Disambiguate the [aurora] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurora) tag has very mixed content. I suggest that we disambiguate this tag.

I think there are mainly two meanings here:

[**Amazon RDS Aurora**](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/) database service, with both MySQL and PostgreSQL dialects. Questions related to this service should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora) instead.

[**Apache Aurora**](http://aurora.apache.org/) - a Mesos framework for long-running services and cron jobs. We should probably create a **new** tag [apache-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-aurora) for this instead.

Of 162 questions:

- 72 is related to [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 54 is related to [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 36 is related to [amazon-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 29 is related to [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 25 is related to [mesos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mesos) - should probably use a **new** tag [apache-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-aurora)
- 19 is related to [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 8 is related to [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)
- 7 is related to [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) - should probably use [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do agree with the suggestion of disambiguating aurora, and this seems to be an easy cleanup compared to the more complicated ones out there. However, we would need a bit of manual intervention here. The following steps would be the best way to cleanup this tag:

1. Go through the set of [38 questions that aren't related to AWS Aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baurora%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bamazon-web-services%5D+-%5Bamazon-aurora%5D+-%5Bamazon-rds%5D+-%5Bmysql%5D++-%22amazon%22+-%22AWS%22&searchOn=3) and retag them manually to [apache-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-aurora). We would need a set of volunteers for this.
2. Once done with that, we would need to merge [aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aurora) with [amazon-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-aurora). We would need a moderator for this
3. Finally, we would need someone to write a good tag wiki for the [apache-aurora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-aurora) tag. We would need some [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mesos/topusers) from related tags for this.

Once done, the two auroras would be separate, just like borealis and australis.